# How to define a View for model with List when list property does not have element

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC. I need help on how I can create the view for this. Lets say user wants to add question. One question can have four answers. While creating question it does not have any answers hence I cannot loop to generate four textboxes. WHat will be the better approach to handle this scenario?

Following are my Models

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Weightage { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not enough aware about the implementation code, below is some code with additional model and modified existing models.

```
public class QuestionAnswers
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Weightage { get; set; }
}
```